# Removing elements from a matrix with list.pop() returns None, or a list index error

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a memory card game where I create a matrix of cards and using user input. The user inputs a row and column of the matrix, and matching them removes the card from the matrix. I've created a matrix where the user can select cards, but I'm having trouble creating a function to remove matched pairs.

```
import random

matrix = None

def create_deck():
    ranks = ['A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K']
    suits = ['♠', '♥', '♣', '♦']

    deck = []

    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            card = str(rank) + suit
            deck.append(card)

    random.shuffle(deck)

    global matrix
    matrix = [[[random.choice(deck), ''] for i in range(13)]for j in range(4)]

    count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    for i in count:
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('')
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            print((matrix[i][j][1]), end = ' ')
        print('')

def get_card():
    row_input = input("Enter row of desired card")
    col_input = input("Enter column of desired card")
    global row
    global col
    row = int(row_input)
    col = int(col_input)
    return matrix[row][col][0]

def remove_pairs():
    matrix[row][col].pop()

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            print((matrix[i][j][1]), end = ' ')
        print('')

if __name__=="__main__":
    create_deck()

    p1_score = 0
    p2_score = 0

    card1 = None
    card2 = None

    while True:
        card1 = get_card()
        card2 = get_card()
```

After I `pop()` the specified card, it either returns a `None`, or a list index error. What am I doing wrong in the `remove_pairs()` function?

Answer (score 0):

What´s happening is that when you pop the card from the deck, the item in `matrix[row][col]` is originally ("card","") and after that it becomes ("card"). So, when you try to print the matrix and finds `matrix[i=row][j=col][1]`, this item has only one element, and you are trying to access the 2nd element, and because it does not exist, it gives you an `IndexError`.
Here is a proposed solution to the problem:

```
def remove_pairs():
    matrix[row][col].pop()

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            try:
                print((matrix[i][j][1]), end = ' ')
            except IndexError:
                print("  ")
        print('')
```